# 二次元配列の値を、値の出現順を変えず、空白は無視してまとめたい

Tags: php

```
$array = array(
  array('name'=>'いちご','id'=>'10'),
  array('id'=>'13'),
  array('name'=>'りんご','id'=>'20'),
  array('id'=>'28'),
  array('name'=>'みかん','id'=>'30'),
  array('name'=>'りんご','id'=>'50'),
  array('name'=>'いちご','id'=>'60'),
)
```

このデータを、nameがないものはそのままで、nameのあるものは、一番最初に出現した同じnameの下にまとめたいとおもっています。

ソート後のイメージとしては、

```
$array = array(
  array('name'=>'いちご','id'=>'10'),
  array('name'=>'いちご','id'=>'60'),
  array('id'=>'13'),
  array('name'=>'りんご','id'=>'20'),
  array('name'=>'りんご','id'=>'50'),
  array('id'=>'28'),
  array('name'=>'みかん','id'=>'30'),
)
```

こういったソートを行う手段をご存知でしたら教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プログラミング言語やライブラリの「ソート」機能は何らかのキーの値に従って順序を並べ替えるものなので、ご自身でちょっとしたコードを書いてやらないといけないだろうと思います。

例えばこんな感じ。

```
<?php

$array = [
  ['name'=>'いちご','id'=>'10'],
  ['id'=>'13'],
  ['name'=>'りんご','id'=>'20'],
  ['id'=>'28'],
  ['name'=>'みかん','id'=>'30'],
  ['name'=>'りんご','id'=>'50'],
  ['name'=>'いちご','id'=>'60'],
];
//'name'の値で分類して、「キー=>配列」の連想配列を作る
$tmp_arr = [];
foreach( $array as $element ) {
  if( array_key_exists('name', $element) ) {
    //'name'キーが存在する場合、同じ'name'値の配列の最後に付け足す
    $tmp_arr[$element['name']][] = $element;
  } else {
    //'name'キーが存在しない場合、1要素配列にして$tmp_arrの最後に付け足す
    $tmp_arr[] = [$element];
  }
}
var_dump($tmp_arr);
/*
`var_dump`の出力は見難いので、省略記法にするとこんな感じになる
$tmp_arr = [
  'いちご' => [['name'=>'いちご','id'=>'10'], ['name'=>'いちご','id'=>'60']],
  0 => [['id'=>'13']],
  ’りんご' => [['name'=>'りんご','id'=>'20'], ['name'=>'りんご','id'=>'50']],
  1 => [['id'=>'28']],
  'みかん' => [['name'=>'みかん','id'=>'30']],
];
 */
//array_mergeで再度結合
//phpの配列は連想配列として使っても順序保存されることを利用している
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $tmp_arr);
var_dump($array);
```

あなたの言い方で言えば三次元配列を中間結果として作成して、それをもう一度つなげなおしています。

(今時5.3以前の古いPHPを使っている人は滅多にいないと思われるので、配列は省略記法にしてあります。)

Comment: ありがとうございました。非常に勉強になりました。最後にarray_mergeを行うと綺麗に結合されるのですね。まだそのあたりの仕組みがわからないので勉強してみます。省略記法も参考になりました。

Answer (score 0):

配列の中で、その配列をidのみのものを最初に抜き出し、その後で元の配列の中から一つのnameをピックアップし、forループをしている時に同じnameがあれば新しい配列にいれて、元の配列からそのnameを含む配列を取り除く。forループし終わった後に、何もnameが見つかっていなければ、新しい配列にあらかじめ用意しておいたidのみの配列を加えるというやり方にしました。

```
<?php

$array       = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'いちご',
        'id' => '10'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '13'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'りんご',
        'id' => '20'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '28'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'みかん',
        'id' => '30'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'りんご',
        'id' => '50'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'いちご',
        'id' => '60'
    )
);
$arraylength = count($array);
$result      = array();//仮の結果。結果として三次元配列になる。
$bararray    = array();// idだけの配列を抜き出す。


for ($j = 0; $j < $arraylength; $j++) {
    if (array_key_exists('id', $array[$j]) == true && array_key_exists('name', $array[$j]) != true) {
        $newarr       = array();
        $newarr['id'] = $array[$j]['id'];
        array_push($bararray, $newarr);
    }
}// idのみの配列を抜き出した。
$j = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $arraylength; $i++) {

    $newarr = array();
    for ($k = $i; $k < $arraylength; $k++) {
        if (array_key_exists('id', $array[$i]) == true && array_key_exists('name', $array[$i]) == true && array_key_exists('name', $array[$k]) == true && $array[$k]['name'] == $array[$i]['name']) {
            array_push($newarr, $array[$k]);
            if ($i != $k) {
                unset($array[$k]);
                $arraylength--;
            }
            ;
        }
    }

    if (!$newarr) {
        array_push($result, $bararray[$j]);
        $j++;
    } else {
        array_push($result, $newarr);
    }
}//仮の結果、三次元配列はここまで

$realresult   = array();//求めたい結果
$resultlength = count($result);
for ($k = 0; $k < $resultlength; $k++) {
    $resultArraylength = count($result[$k]);
    if ($resultArraylength == 1) {
        if (is_array($result[$k]) == true && array_key_exists(0, $result[$k]) == false) {
            array_push($realresult, $result[$k]);
        } else {
            array_push($realresult, $result[$k]['0']);
        }

    } else {
        for ($m = 0; $m < $resultArraylength; $m++) {
            array_push($realresult, $result[$k][$m]);
        }
    }

}
print_r($realresult);
?>
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。こういった配列を並び替えるには、三次元配列を作る必要があるのですね。配列の並び替えでつまることなどが多いので、そういう時のためにこのコードを見て勉強させていただきます。

Comment: @pelomococo 特に三次元配列にする必要はないそうです。PHPに搭載されている関数を使えば、[このように](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c002666496a779813d71407dcc72f96b385a9b4)出来るようです。僕も気になったので [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184419/php-multi-dimensional-array-performance-improvement)で聞きました。必要でしたらご確認して見てください。大分簡潔になっています。

Comment: 大変参考になりました。このように簡潔にまとめることもできるのですね。質問までしてくださってありがとうございます。